# No module named 'simple_unet_model'

Tags: python, import, module

I try to import "simple_unet_model" but I get the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'simple_unet_model'

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? please.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln4PB.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first take the  [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) How to ask a good question. Please [do not post images of code or error messages](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) - post as text here

Answer (score -1):

Try to install

```
pip install unet
```

or you can try

```
import simple_unet_model
```